# Why are our toilets not flushing correctly after our septic system was cleaned?

Tags: plumbing, septic, septic-tanks

We just our septic tanks cleaned.  The lines had suction applied. Now neither of our toilets will flush correctly. The water will drain out but the paper will not go down.

Any suggestions as to our next move?

Comment: Does the toilet look like it's taking a gulp of air when you flush? Or a big bubble coming up?

Comment: Sounds like the plugged the vent line in the process.

Answer (score 1):

As a retired country plumber, I would advise against suction or pressure systems.  They are a no- no in older septic tank installations particularly ones using salt glaze fire clay pipes with cemented joints.  Such pipes are very liable to collapse or obstructions produced by fillets of loose cement that clog up the free flow of the flush. Stick to conventional drain rods and muscle.